# How can I turn off includeSubDomains for HSTS in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https, hsts

I don't want the `includeSubDomains` option

```
➔ curl -s --head https://example.com/ |grep Strict 
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
```

This doesn't seem to be working:

```
config.force_ssl = true
config.ssl_options = { hsts: { subdomains: false } }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Rails 5.0.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that Rails 5 has an initializer, new_framework_defaults.rb, which has this line:

```
Rails.application.config.ssl_options = { hsts: { subdomains: true } }
```

Because it's in an initializer, no matter what you put in the environment config, those settings don't have an effect. I opened an issue about this here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27638

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend using the [secureheaders gem](https://github.com/twitter/secureheaders) so you get better control over these headers (and other similar ones).